# Java mail message reading exception when sending a mail through java 6 with port 465

Tags: jakarta-mail, java-7, java-6

Hi I am sending an email through java application.

When I am running the code through java 7, mails sends properly.

But when I am running the code through java 6, I got following exception

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1611)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
at com.demo.MySendMails.sendMail(MySendMails.java:477)
at com.demo.MySendMails.BirthDayMail(MySendMails.java:291)
at com.demo.MySendMails.main(MySendMails.java:535)
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:785)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:88)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1589)
... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
... 22 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
... 28 more
```

Here I am using gmail as my mail server and i am using following propertie

```
Properties props = new Properties();    
props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); //SSL Factory class
```

I am not shore because of using 465 port do I need to enable SSL and key value should be smtps instead smtp, in email properties?

Is there any certification to be enabled in java 6 for sending a mail using smtp protocall.

If any such guide me in resolving the above issue

Comment: [Get rid of the socket factory properties.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  And your properties have the host and port settings backwards; I don't know how that ever worked.  If you explicitly ask for the `smtps` Transport in your code, then you need to set the `mail.smtps.*` properties.  If you just use the default (smtp), then setting the `mail.smtp.*` properties is correct.  If none of this solves your problem, post your code and the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but what does it mean "properties have the host and port settings backwards"

Comment: 465 isn't a host name, it's a port number, but you set it as the value of the mail.smtp.host property.

Comment: No it's wrongly posted and now i have corrected it.

Comment: The accuracy of my help is a function of the accuracy of the information you post.  :-)

Comment: @BillShannon could u suggest me why this `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.    After using this property `props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory")` in my code.

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't make any difference, but there may be differences in the way the default configuration is used in the two cases, allowing it to find or not find the trust store that contains the required certificates.